# Connection denied when i use flume to post file to HDFS in real-time display

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2, flume

i am a beignner of flume,when i try to write a template to study how to use flume of handling posting file to HDFS in real-time,i got a error about connection denied.
what i want to do in template:
-->using flume to collect log created by hive,and post it to HDFS

here is my job_conf

```
#name sources,sinks,and channels
a2.sources=r2
a2.sinks=k2
a2.channels=c2

#sources conf,specify the log file i want to watch
a2.sources.r2.type=exec
a2.sources.r2.command = tail -F /opt/module/hive/logs/hive.log
a2.sources.r2.shell=/bin/bash -c

#sinks conf
a2.sinks.k2.type = hdfs
#connect porperties
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.path = hdfs://hadoop102/flume/%Y%m%d/%H
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.filePrefix = hive_log-
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.round = true
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.roundValue = 1
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.roundUnit = hour
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollInterval = 600
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollSize = 134217700
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.rollCount = 0
a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.minBlockReplicas = 1

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a2.channels.c2.type = memory
a2.channels.c2.capacity = 1000
a2.channels.c2.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a2.sources.r2.channels = c2
a2.sinks.k2.channel = c2
```

errors info of flume.log below

```
 03 July 2019 00:21:41,002 INFO  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.open:231)  - Creating hdfs://hadoop102/flume/20190703/00/logs-.1562084496871.tmp
03 July 2019 00:21:41,132 WARN  [SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor] (org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process:443)  - HDFS IO error
java.net.ConnectException: Call From hadoop102/192.168.1.102 to hadoop102:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: 拒绝连接(connection denied); For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:296)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1652)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1689)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$7.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:448)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$7.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:909)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:890)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:787)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:776)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSDataStream.doOpen(HDFSDataStream.java:81)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSDataStream.open(HDFSDataStream.java:108)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:242)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:232)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:668)
        at org.apache.flume.auth.SimpleAuthenticator.execute(SimpleAuthenticator.java:50)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:665)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: 拒绝连接(connection denied)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
        ... 34 more
```

it looks so wired that i get expected file in HDFS if i change

```
     a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.path = hdfs://hadoop102/flume/%Y%m%d/%H
to
      a2.sinks.k2.hdfs.path = /flume/%Y%m%d/%H
```

i guess when i do not specify hdfs://hadoop102,flume will load hadoop configuration to info of hadoop cluster.

by the way,i have seen such a info in flume official website

```
hdfs.path   –   HDFS directory path (eg hdfs://namenode/flume/webdata/)
```

and a example given by flume website

```
a1.channels = c1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /flume/events/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/%S
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events-
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = true
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute
```

it alse do not specify hadoop cluster ip

Answer (score 0):

If the node on which you are running the flume agent is part of the Hadoop eco-system, like if that node is configured as hadoop client machine then you can give the direct folder path without providing scheme and namenode information, if that node is not part of the eco system then you need to provide the full path, like: `hdfs://name-node:port/flume/...`.